# How can I make the sql code within my python code adjustable?

Tags: python, sql, database

Hi everyone I was wondering if it is possible to make SQL code within python code adjustable through input function? I am currently trying this code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('season.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

season_number = input('Enter season id:')

sqlstr = '''SELECT a.home_team AS team_name, a.Points+b.Points as Points
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT t.name AS home_team, s.name, SUM(CASE
                                         WHEN substr(m.result,1,1) > substr(m.result,-1,1) THEN '3'
                                         WHEN substr(m.result,1,1) < substr(m.result,-1,1) THEN '0'
                                         WHEN substr(m.result,1,1) = substr(m.result,-1,1) THEN '1'
                                         END) AS Points
FROM Match m JOIN Team t
ON t.id=home_team_id
JOIN Season s
ON s.id = m.season_id
WHERE season_id = season_number
GROUP BY t.name
ORDER BY Points DESC) AS a

JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT t.name AS guest_team, s.name, SUM(CASE
                                         WHEN substr(m.result,1,1) < substr(m.result,-1,1) THEN '3'
                                         WHEN substr(m.result,1,1) > substr(m.result,-1,1) THEN '0'
                                         WHEN substr(m.result,1,1) = substr(m.result,-1,1) THEN '1'
                                         END) AS Points
FROM Match m JOIN Team t
ON t.id=guest_team_id
JOIN Season s
ON s.id = m.season_id
WHERE season_id = season_number
GROUP BY t.name
ORDER BY Points DESC) AS b
ON a.home_team=b.guest_team
ORDER BY Points DESC'''

cur.execute(sqlstr)
result = cur.fetchall()
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

But obviously, I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analysis.py", line 38, in <module>
    cur.execute(sqlstr)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: season_number
```

So I was wondering, is there a way to include this input function into SQL code so I can slice the database whichever way I want?

I hope I explained the issue well enough for it to be understandable. I am a newbie so please let me know if you need more info to answer the question.

Comment: What SQL technology are you using?  Have you looked into Stored Procedures? They are better for these types of queries/

Comment: Use a parametrized sql? http://bobby-tables.com/python

Comment: I am using SQLite

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/ is a laught worth - just google for sql injection and do not try to escape strings yourself into your sql ;) thats how I remember the bobby tables url by - and it showes syntax for multiple sqlish langs.